# How to print Array

Tags: magento2

I am getting result in array like this now I want make drop down of this label and value

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [value] => default [label] => Default Source )
    [1] => Array ( [value] => Dropship [label] => Dropship Items )
    [2] => Array ( [value] => test [label] => warehouse )
)
```

I want to create a select dropdown of the above array. How do I get this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question belongs to www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach to print it as dropdown, Instead of **$array** use your variable

```
<select>
    <?php if(!empty($array)) {
        foreach($array as $key => $val) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $val['value'] ?>">
                <?php echo $val['label']; ?>
            </option><?php 
        }
    } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: i tried this but its show last value not all values but when i use print r its show all

Comment: Only 1( last Option) option showing in dropdown ?

Comment: yes Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => default [label] => Default Source ) [1] => Array ( [value] => Dropship [label] => Dropship Items ) [2] => Array ( [value] => test [label] => warehouse ) ) just showing ware house using loop foreach

Comment: Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal string offset 'value' in

Comment: Could you check now again i have updated

Comment: pefect thanks done

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this format to show options.

```
<?php    

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class OptionsDropDown implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            ['label' => 'False', 'value' => 0],
            ['label' => 'True', 'value' => 1]
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how get this in phtm file

Comment: this code return me array as i mentioned now i want display in normal dropdown not configratuion

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<select name=""> 
<?php foreach($array as $arr): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $arr['value']; ?>"><?php echo $arr['label']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

$array is the variable of your array which you are getting from result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do below step which can be help to resolved your problem:

```
<?php $collectionArr = array(0=>array('value'=>'default', 'label'=>'Default Source'),
             1=>array('value'=>'Dropship', 'label'=>'Dropship Items'),
             2=>array('value'=>'test', 'label'=>'warehouse')
           ); <select name=""> <?php foreach($collectionArr as $collectionArrValue): ?><option value="<?php echo $collectionArrValue['value']; ?>">
```

Thanks